# I'm unable to create a seaborn boxplot, I get a TypeError and don't know how to troubleshoot it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn, boxplot

I'm trying to create a boxplot graph with seaborn. I've tried troubleshooting and I've looked all over the Internet for an answer but I haven't been able to find something useful. 
In advance, thank you all for your time and help/feedback. If there's any more info that would help you, please let me know.

A sample of my DataFrame is as follows:

| Week | Team | Margin | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | -10 | R |
| 1 | B | -5 | R |
| 1 | C | -15 | R |
| 1 | D | 15 | R |
| 1 | E | 5 | R |
| 1 | F | 10 | R |

*(Total number of rows is 170)*

The DataFrame type for each column is:

1. Week:        int64
2. Team:       object
3. Margin:    float64
4. Type:       object

- dtype: object

The code that I'm trying to run is:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(16, 6))

sns.boxplot(data=df5, x='Team', y='Margin',
            hue='Type', palette='muted')

ax.axhline(0, ls='--')
ax.set_xlabel('Teams')
ax.set_title('Win/Loss Margin')
```

To get a graph like this:

[image: Boxplot graph by Steven Morse for FFootball]

But I get a long Traceback, but where it first finds an error is on:

```
sns.boxplot(data=df5, x='Team', y='Margin',
```

that ends with:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Team' and 'Team'
```

The full Traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): <br />
  **File "/test.py", line 76, in <module>** <br />
    sns.boxplot(data=df5, x='Team', y='Margin', <br />
  **File "/Packages/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seaborn/_decorators.py", line 46, in inner_f** <br />
    return f(**kwargs) <br />
  **File "/Packages/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py", line 2243, in boxplot** <br />
    plotter = _BoxPlotter(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, <br />
  **File "/Packages/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py", line 406, in __init__** <br />
    self.establish_variables(x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order) <br />
  **File "/Packages/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py", line 206, in establish_variables** <br />
    plot_data, value_label = self._group_longform(vals, groups, <br />
  **File "/Packages/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py", line 257, in _group_longform** <br />
    g_vals = grouped_vals.get_group(g) <br />
  **File "/Packages/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 745, in get_group** <br />
    inds = self._get_index(name) <br />
  **File "/Packages/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 673, in _get_index** <br />
    return self._get_indices([name])[0] <br />
  **File "/Packages/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 637, in _get_indices** <br />
    if len(self.indices) > 0: <br />
  **File "/Packages/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 915, in __getattribute__** <br />
    return super().__getattribute__(attr) <br />
  **File "/Packages/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 615, in indices** <br />
    return self.grouper.indices <br />
  **File "pandas/_libs/properties.pyx", line 37, in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__** <br />
  **File "/Packages/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py", line 783, in indices** <br />
    if len(self.groupings) == 1 and isinstance(self.result_index, CategoricalIndex): <br />
  **File "pandas/_libs/properties.pyx", line 37, in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__** <br />
  **File "/Packages/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py", line 893, in result_index** <br />
    return self.groupings[0].result_index.rename(self.names[0]) <br />
  **File "pandas/_libs/properties.pyx", line 37, in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__** <br />
  **File "/Packages/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py", line 648, in result_index** <br />
    return self.group_index <br />
  **File "pandas/_libs/properties.pyx", line 37, in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__** <br />
  **File "/Packages/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py", line 656, in group_index** <br />
    uniques = self._codes_and_uniques[1] <br />
  **File "pandas/_libs/properties.pyx", line 37, in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__** <br />
  **File "/Packages/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py", line 690, in _codes_and_uniques** <br />
    codes, uniques = algorithms.factorize( <br />
  **File "/Packages/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 768, in factorize** <br />
    uniques, codes = safe_sort( <br />
  **File "/Packages/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 1736, in safe_sort** <br />
    ordered = _sort_mixed(values) <br />
  **File "/Packages/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 1800, in _sort_mixed** <br />
    nums = np.sort(values[~str_pos]) <br />
  **File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in sort** <br />
  **File "/Packages/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 1004, in sort** <br />
    a.sort(axis=axis, kind=kind, order=order) <br />
**TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Team' and 'Team'**
```

Comment: Make sure matplotlib and seaborn are updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample data is inadequate to draw the box plot using `Team` and `Margin` and hence I added few more rows

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Week" : [1] * 6 + [2] * 6,
    "Team": ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
    "Margin": [-10, -5, -15, 15, 5, 10, 10, 5, 15, -15, -10, 5],
    "Type": ["R"] * 12
})
```

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.boxplot(data=df, x="Week", y="Margin")
```

[image: week margin box plot]

```
sns.boxplot(data=df, x="Team", y="Margin", hue='Type', palette='muted')
```

[image: Team Margin box plot]

Seaborn version - `0.11.0`

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! From what I get to understand from the df that you created, was to double the entries?
What I ended up doing was changing the Team from strings to integers and that allowed the box plot to show, then I just changed the xticklabels back to the teams' actual names.
I'm intrigued on knowing why with strings pops up an error but not with int. But at this point I don't even know if that's actually the error.

Comment: glad that you figured it out